# Ionic analytics doesn’t work

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, analytics

I am following these tutorials
[tutorial1](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/analytics-from-scratch) and [tutorial2](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/analytics-install)

and I have done a lot of researching, nothing works =(

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngSanitize', 'ionic.service.core', 'ionic.service.analytics'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform,$ionicAnalytics) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

$ionicAnalytics.register();


// Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
// for form inputs)
 if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true); }
if(window.StatusBar) {
 //StatusBar.styleDefault();
StatusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
StatusBar.style(1)
}
});
})
```

This is the error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ionic.service.core due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ionic.service.core' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/nomod?p0=ionic.service.core
```

Comment: try var object = angular.module(...) and see

Comment: Hi i am facing same problem but now i am using [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com) for android app and for browser direct using google analytics script.

Comment: Did you run:

    ionic add ionic-platform-web-client

Answer (score 0):

Run `ionic config build`

Not completely sure why this is necessary, I assume when calling `ionic add ionic-platform-web` the config files are not modified.

This step is also necessary when cloning the repo into another machine, which is how I ran into the error.

Got the solution from here: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-platform-web-client/issues/29